# Trend line does not seem to fit data

Tags: r, data-visualization, linear-model

I'm trying to do a simple scatterplot and trend line in R, but it doesn't look right. Have I messed up something blatantly obvious? Any ideas as to why the line doesn't fit the data?

[image: the trend line does not fit the data]

Here is the code I used.

```
> plot(x, y, pch=".")
> model <- lm(x ~ y)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.23043 -0.04340 -0.00533  0.03761  0.47882 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.051154   0.001384   36.97   <2e-16 ***
y           0.462881   0.003739  123.80   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.06365 on 71514 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.1765, Adjusted R-squared: 0.1765 
F-statistic: 1.533e+04 on 1 and 71514 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16 

> abline(model, col="red")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change

```
model <- lm(x ~ y)
```

to

```
model <- lm(y ~ x).
```

Currently your fitline is showing x as a function of y instead of verse-vica.